# PHP HTMLEntities for specific elements

Tags: php, html-entities

I am working with `htmlentites()` to replace characters with safe html, namely the PHP because I want to be able to show PHP examples. The problem I am running into is all the tags are replaced (ex: `</p>`, `</br>` etc). I know I can write a custom htmentities to only replace the `<?` tags and other specific xml tags but I was wondering is there something in PHP that already does this?

Comment: It appears that stakoverflow tags actual convert to html....its this an error or do I have to escape them on here to display them

Comment: Still I don't actually understand what you are talking about.

Comment: @Charliepiga - nice edit, far faster than what I did...

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [`highlight_string()` function in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php) as it will escape the characters and syntax highlight the code.